# Grab all html tags from string including their content (Regex Only)

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am trying to get all html tags, without exception, from a string. Just to clarify, it needs to be strictly string only, without converting into html object. I created one regex but it only grabs the tags without the content.

```js
var text = '<div class="mura-region-local"><p>In October 2010, Lisa and Eugene Jeffers learned that their daughter Jade, then nearly 2 and a half years old, has autism. The diagnosis felt like a double whammy. The parents were soon engulfed by stress from juggling Jade’s new therapy appointments and wrangling with their health insurance provider, but they now had an infant son to worry about, too. Autism runs in families. Would Bradley follow in his big sister’s footsteps?</p></div><img href=""/>'

var match = text.match(/<?\w+((\s+\w+(\s*=\s*(?:".*?"|'.*?'|[\^'">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)?>/g);

console.log(match);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: _"I created one regex but it only grabs the the tags without the content"._ The result would be the existing string, yes?

Comment: @NisargShah, this question is not the same... Their solution don't work and they suggesting to use plugins...... I strictly mentioned that I want to grab all the html tags including their respective content

Comment: yes, @guest271314

Comment: Then what is purpose of `RegExp` on the HTML string at Question?

Comment: str.match(RegExp).map(function(val){return val;}); and be able to loop this array. I need to do some logic for every P tag found

Comment: Could you add some example of what exactly you're expecting as a result?

Comment: H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ

Answer (score 0):

You can't find pairs of `<smth>...</smth>` for all possible tags. You can't make regex that will recognize tagA inside tagB and tagB in tagA for all tags, too. You must write all these combinations directly, and that makes such regex impossible.

But if you mean that you want to take only `<smth ....>`, `</smth>` and `<smth..../>` tags without checking the correct order of them, it IS possible.

```
<(?:\w+(?:\s+\w+=(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'))*\/?|(?:\/\w+))>
```

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/6qP6RI/1/) is the test.

Comment: how about the content inside the html tags?

Comment: this works for the html tags only but no the content

Comment: @JoseCC Read above and read the reference of Nisarg. It is practically impossible. Or you must openly write down a variant regex group for every allowed tag and every their possible combination of including. For 20 tags and allowed only one level of including you have 400 regex groups. And each of them is very complex by itself.